# How do you make a holding circuit in LTSpice?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, ltspice, amplitude-modulation

[image]

How do you make this figure in LTSpice?

Comment: What operates the switch?

Answer (score 3):

Either you use a capacitor (<kbd>C</kbd>) and a switch (<kbd>F2</kbd> -> `sw`) driven by some voltage source, or use `[SpecialFunctions]/sample`. See the schematic `SampleandHold.asc` in the *My Documents/LTspiceXVII/exmaples/Educational/* folder (and don't forget about the help: *LTspice > Circuit Elements > A. ...*).